# NextJS case insensitive route for SSG pages

Tags: next.js, url-routing

I am using NextJS to translate a CSV of data into static pages. Each page is `pages/[slug].jsx`. I'm calling `toLowerCase()` on the slug value inside [slug].jsx `getStaticPaths()` and `getStaticProps()` functions. The generated pages are lowercase. e.g. /ab101, /ab102, /cc500 all resolve to the pages/[slug].jsx page.

Unfortunately, people might **hand type** the url and may use caps or mixed case for the slug value, currently resulting in a 404.

QUESTION: How can I make routing case insensitive with respect to the slug value?

**UPDATE**

When I return `fallback: true` from `getStaticPaths()`, my `[slug].jsx` file is hit even when there is not an exact path match. I can then check `isFallback` as illustrated by Anish Antony below.

Additionally, the `items` param that is passed to my page will be undefined when the page wasn't found. The router's `pathname` value is `"/[slug]"` and not the value of "slug". However, there is an `asPath` value which contains useful data, e.g. `/mixedCaseSlug?param=value&foo=bar`.

When the page renders, I check if it's a fallback. If it is, show a LOADING... message. Next will display that and call getStaticProps() to generate the "missing" page. You'll then re-render with the page data. In the event that getStaticProps couldn't get page data, I push a path that will lead to the built-in 404 page.

```
export default function Page({ item }) {
  const { isFallback, push } = useRouter()
  const hasPageData = item && Object.keys(item).length > 0
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isFallback && !hasPageData) {
      push('/page-not-found/error')
    }
  }, [isFallback, hasPageData])
  const loadingMsg = <div>Loading...</div>
  const notFoundMsg = <div>Page not found</div>
  return isFallback ? loadingMsg : hasPageData ? <Item item={item} /> : notFoundMsg
}
```

I needed to update `getStaticProps()` to lowercase the `slug` param, as it may now be mixed case, but we want to find our page data. And I needed to allow for the case when there really is no data for the slug.

```
export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const { slug } = params
  const item = data.find(o => o.Practice_Code.trim().toLowerCase() === slug.toLowerCase())
  return {
    props: {
      item: item ? item : {}
    }
  }
}
```

This all seems very kludgy, so I'm still wondering if there is a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NextJS routes are case sensitive.You can use fallback property in getStaticPaths to catch the routes which aren't in the same case as the one provided by default in getStaticPaths.

Edit: I have updated the answer based on the discussion with Dave.

We can give fallback:true or fallback:"blocking" , if we give fallback:true we we can show a custom component which will be displayed till the time page is loaded.For fallback:"blocking" new paths not returned by getStaticPaths will wait for the HTML to be generated,

When we give fallback:true or "blocking" static page will be generated when the user first access the site and the generated page will be served for further visits.

Sample code

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const idList = await fetchAllIds();
  const paths = [
  ];
  idList.forEach((id) => {paths.push(`/posts/${id}`)})
  return { paths, fallback: true };
}
```

What we have note is our code in getStaticProps should be case insensitive to get the data irrespective of the one provided in url.

```
export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const { slug } = params;

 try {
    /// This fetch api should be able to fetch the data irrespective of the case of the slug 
or we should convert it to the required case before passing it as a parameter to API
    const data= await fetchSlugDetails(slug);
//Same logic should be performed if you are getting data filtered based on slug from an existing array.
    return data? { props: { data} } : { notFound: true };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return { notFound: true };
  }

}
```

Note: You have to handle the notfound case and fallback case if you are using fallback:true. For fallback you can get the value isFallback from next/router while the page is being static generated

Comment: thanks. Where does that useEffect() go? My pages/[slug].jsx page doesn't appear to get hit. Is there more to the solution, e.g. adding routes somewhere or getStaticPaths() fallback param?

Comment: Yes I use fallback:true with getStaticPaths and use isFallback in my component, I have edited the answer with sample code from my app. (The code is working as expeted after vercel deployment)

Comment: I've accepted your answer since it pointed me in the right direction. But, it doesn't work as-is. At least not for the current version of NextJS. Thank you for the tip about returning fallback: true.

Comment: Okay, I am using 10.0.3. If you could please post the working code in current version when you get it working.

Comment: I added it as an update at the bottom of my question.

Comment: Based on your answer ,I got how my code was working , I was converting the slug to lowercase in my code. That was the main reason along with fallback for my code to work. I have updated the answer based on it